# Arithmetic, Geometric, Harmonic Means

Tags: soft-question, arithmetic, average

There are situations in which just one of the arithmetic, geometric, and harmonic means are appropriate to use an the other two are meaningless.

**Is there any situation which more than one of these means are meaningful and have good interpretations?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There a lot of means (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean). In engineering, some fundamental equations involve equations in which the logarithmic mean is used and this is a quite expensive operation; so, some people found very nice approximations based on a linear combination of arithmetic and geometric means. If you are interested, let me know; we should continue.